# Confluent Platform KSQL in headless mode

Tags: ksqldb, confluent-platform

I've read through KSQL deployment options here https://www.confluent.jp/blog/deep-dive-ksql-deployment-options/. So it is recommended to use headless KSQL for production deployment.

But I have not found any hints on how I can stop/change queries when in production (headless) mode when KSQL disables interactive access to server via REST/CLI. Does that mean that I need to shut down all KSQL servers in order to add/change one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deloy headless or interactive into Production, depending on what meets your needs.

Headless is designed to allow you to run a known set of queries in a locked down fashion.  This can be a requirement for production systems with strict SLAs, where you don't want someone connecting and kicking off an expensive query or dropping something that causes SLAs to be broken.

As you correctly identify, the Headless deployment mode doesn't allow you to change the DDL of your cluster through a CLI/API.  Instead, it would be more normal to have some kind of automation around updating the SQL file and bouncing the cluster. We are aware there is much room for improvement here.

Keep in mind that KSQL does not, at the time of writing, support updating an existing table or stream.  However, this is something we're actively working towards.  Until that is supported, in general you should only add queries to the file. Any deletions or changes to existing queries would require careful testing as there are many changes KSQL does not currently support. Always ensure changes are thoroughly testing before any prod deployment. Alternatively, some users spin up new clusters when changes need to be made, (hopefully infrequently!). Once caught up, they fail over clients and turn of the old cluster. Again, this is an area in which KSQL will see improvements.

Hope this helps and thanks for using KSQL!